# Scala Swing image

Tags: image, swing, scala

How do I load and display an image in a Scala Swing component?

Comment: What does Scala have to do with it?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson -- scala revamped swing. I'd like to use images in a way that's consistent with the revamp.

Comment: OK, got it.  Seems my answer was way off track then.  :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually use Label with ImageIcon for that ... like:

```
val label = new Label {
  icon = new ImageIcon("path to the image file")
}
```

Comment: That's a `javax.swing.ImageIcon`, I assume.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an implementation of an `ImagePanel` that extends scala's `Panel`

```
import swing._                                                                

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage                                           
import java.io.File                                                           
import javax.imageio.ImageIO                                                  

class ImagePanel extends Panel                                                
{                                                                             
  private var _imagePath = ""                                                 
  private var bufferedImage:BufferedImage = null                              

  def imagePath = _imagePath                                                  

  def imagePath_=(value:String)                                               
  {                                                                           
    _imagePath = value                                                        
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(_imagePath))                        
  }                                                                           


  override def paintComponent(g:Graphics2D) =                                 
  {                                                                           
    if (null != bufferedImage) g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null)         
  }                                                                           
}                                                                             

object ImagePanel                                                             
{                                                                             
  def apply() = new ImagePanel()                                              
}
```

Usage:

```
object ImagePanelDemo extends SimpleSwingApplication
{

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Image Panel Demo"

    contents = new ImagePanel
    {   
      imagePath = ("../testImage.jpg")
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: You may also wish to set `preferredSize` to the image dimensions, at least up to some maximum value (e.g. screen size).