# ImagePanel adaptation in scala

Tags: image, swing, scala, panel, gridpanel

I am starting with the code which was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752330/scala-swing-image) and can be seen below:

```
import swing._                                                                

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage                                           
import java.io.File                                                           
import javax.imageio.ImageIO                                                  

class ImagePanel extends Panel                                                
{                                                                             
  private var _imagePath = ""                                                 
  private var bufferedImage:BufferedImage = null                              

  def imagePath = _imagePath                                                  

  def imagePath_=(value:String)                                               
  {                                                                           
    _imagePath = value                                                        
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(_imagePath))                        
  }                                                                           


  override def paintComponent(g:Graphics2D) =                                 
  {                                                                           
    if (null != bufferedImage) g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null)         
  }                                                                           
}                                                                             

object ImagePanel                                                             
{                                                                             
  def apply() = new ImagePanel()                                              
}
```

Usage:

```
object ImagePanelDemo extends SimpleSwingApplication
{

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Image Panel Demo"

    contents = new ImagePanel
    {   
      imagePath = ("../testImage.jpg")
    }   
  }
}
```

I want to extend this and give the image panel the form of a GridPanel.  I want the Image panel to be a GridPanel with an image background.  Does anyone know how to implement this?

My current implementation is as follows:

```
class ImagePanel(rows0: Int, cols0: Int) extends GridPanel(rows0, cols0)                                                
{                                                                             
  private var _imagePath = ""                                                 
  private var bufferedImage:BufferedImage = null                              

  def imagePath = _imagePath                                                  

  def imagePath_=(value:String)                                               
  {                                                                           
    _imagePath = value                                                        
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(_imagePath))                        
  }                                                                           


  override def paintComponent(g:Graphics2D) =                                 
  {                                                                           
    if (null != bufferedImage) g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null)         
  }                                                                           
}                                                                             

object ImagePanel                                                             
{                                                                             
  def apply() = new ImagePanel()                                              
}
```

I get an error in the object ImagePanel.  I have too few arguments.  I don't know how to exactly add the new arguments of rows and columns here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to subclass `GridPanel` instead. If you change your first line for

```
class ImagePanel(rows0: Int, cols0: Int) extends GridPanel(rows0, cols0)
```

it works.

**EDIT:**

I don't know what error you get—of course now you need to create the `ImagePanel` with arguments for the number of rows and columns...

```
import scala.swing._
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.net.URL
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

class ImagePanel(rows0: Int, cols0: Int) extends GridPanel(rows0, cols0) {
  private var _imagePath = ""                                                 
  private var buf = Option.empty[BufferedImage]

  def imagePath = _imagePath
  def imagePath_=(value: String): Unit = {
    _imagePath = value
    buf.foreach(_.flush()); buf = None
    buf = Some(ImageIO.read(new URL(value)))
    repaint()
  }

  override def paintComponent(g: Graphics2D): Unit = {
    super.paintComponent(g)
    buf.foreach(g.drawImage(_, 0, 0, null))
  }
}

val f        = new Frame()
val p        = new ImagePanel(3, 2)
p.imagePath  = "http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/lib/package_big.png"
p.contents ++= Seq.tabulate(p.rows * p.columns)(i => new Label((i + 1).toString))
f.contents   = p
f.visible    = true
```

Comment: I tried doing exactly this but i get an error in the object ImagePanel.  its a not enough arguments error

Comment: i just removed the Object ImagePanel statements and it worked perfectly.  I spent a very long time debugging an error that was simply fixed by removing the code.

Comment: Of course, in your original code you are adding an `apply` method to the companion object that calls `new ImagePanel()`—now that you have arguments for the `ImagePanel` constructor, you cannot just omit them!

Comment: but everytime I added them i got a different error.  I am a java developer struggling with scala.  I don't see the purpose of the apply method here

Comment: You don't need to companion object and the apply at all to instantiate `ImagePanel`. It would only serve the purpose to use your class in pattern matching (very unlikely for a GUI widget), or as a more convenient syntax for instantiation (given you had `def apply( cols: Int, rows: Int ) = new ImagePanel( cols, rows )` in the companion object, you could create a panel just with `ImagePanel( 3, 2 )` in the above example, sparing the `new` keyword. I highly recommend reading the book by Odersky and Spoon if you are coming new to Scala from Java.