# how to execute a command in scala?

Tags: scala

I want to execute this command "dot -Tpng overview.dot > overview.png ", which is used to generate an image by Graphviz.

The code in scala:

```
Process(Seq("dot -Tpng overview.dot > overview.png"))
```

It does not work.
And I also want to open this image in scala. I work under Ubuntu. By default, images will be opened by image viewer. But I type "eog overview.png" in terminal, it reports error

```
** (eog:18371): WARNING **: The connection is closed
```

Thus, I do not know how to let scala open this image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752330/scala-swing-image can help you in displaying the image.

Comment: @Yang, I have solved this problem, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't redirect `stdout` using `>` in command string. You should use `#>` and `#|` operators. See examples in `process` package [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.package).

This writes `test` into `test.txt`:

```
import scala.sys.process._
import java.io.File

// use scala.bat instead of scala on Windows
val cmd = Seq("scala", "-e", """println(\"test\")""") #> new File("test.txt")
cmd.!
```

In your case:

```
val cmd = "dot -Tpng overview.dot" #> new File("overview.png")
cmd.!
```

Or just this (since `dot` accepts output file name as `-ooutfile`):

```
"dot -Tpng overview.dot -ooverview.png".!
```

Comment: ,thanks for your help. But now eclipse reports "overview.png: Permission denied". I think I should use command "su root". But I do not how to type in my password in code. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @city: You should just specify filename id directory you can use. For instance: `new File("/home/city/overview.png")`.

Comment: @city: alternatively you could run `scala` from root.